# How to reference a specific group of customers

Tags: javascript, authentication, global-variables, bigcommerce

I need to be able to allow a customer (or group of customers in this case) to register for the store, and I need to be able to reference that group of customers in the code somehow, for example:

```
if (currentUserIdOfSomeSort === 9) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

THE CATCH: I need to be able to accomplish this without the need for a person to go into BC and change a setting on the customer - if I have to go and assign the customer a specific group id, then that is not a solution because it involves human intervention.

Everything also needs to be local, as in I am not able to configure an external server to make API calls for specific information (for example, if I added a 'code' field to  the registration form - I already asked, this will not create a new variable for that field, and I am told you would need to use a separate server to make the API call to return that info, something I do not know how to do)

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way to create your own custom global variables as these are functions of the core app. If you wanted to call to the API, you'd need to use [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) (or your own server of choice) to make a request to the API. It can be a purely cURL request or you can use an API client.

```
curl --request GET \
-u "_username_:_API_key_"\
https://store.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/customers/{id}.json
```

You can pass that into a js file hosted on the same server and then load the javascript on your storefront.

```
<script src="https://myserver.com/favoritenumber.js"></script>
```

You'd also need to do some validation that you were displaying this to the correct customer. I'd elect to use CustomerID instead of CustomerName and validate against this.

Comment: I have to use "Some Number" so that I can give someone a number, have then sign up with it, and then my code would reference everyone with that number.  I can't use customer group because that requires a human to go in and assign certain customers to a group by hand, needs to be automated.  Using an external server is just not an option for me, I do not know how to make API calls.  Is the code above all you need?  What are you passing to the JS file?

Comment: You'd need more than what I posted above. The other caveat is that the only other way to get that data is to make an API call via javascript from the storefront, but that is *very* insecure. You expose an API key that gives access to all API exposed basic auth information in your store.